# How to store multi-player keys settings in a simple game?

Tags: c#, performance, oop

I've got a simple WinForms game where player can drive a car on the form. There can be more cars each driven by different player.

When a key is pressed, Form1_KeyDown is fired. Now I need to determine:

1. which player pressed the key
2. what does the key stands for (e.g. go up, go down, go left.. )

The only solution I came with was creating a Keys array for every player where each index would mean a different command (e.g. array[0] = go up, array[1] = go down, etc.)

```
public Keys[] keyControls = new Keys[5]; // up, down, left, right and fire key codes!
```

Then I would have to iterate through every Player and every Key to find the right one, so something like:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Car car in cars)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < car.keyControls.length; i++)
        {
           if (car.keyControls[i] == e.KeyData)
           {
              // save car, index (for movement type) and double break the loops with flags
           }
        }
    }

    // do something with found car and movement index (movement type)
}
```

But I would like to have as "nice" and optimized code as possible, so I was thinking about using some Linq like:

```
Cars car = cars.First(t => t.keyControls.Any( m => m == e.KeyData));
```

But in that case I won't be able to get the index of the movement, so I won't be be able to determine what to do with the car.

Should I store the key data in some different "object"? Or is it possible to get the index from Linq without going through the loop one more time to find what the index stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a dictionary or generic dictionary where you could store a key for fast lookups and an object representing any other data you need to know to act upon that lookup.  A dictionary is going to be much faster than iterating a collection or using linq.